# Bar width in Sibelius

Tags: sibelius

I'm using Sibelius 7.5 and I want to have some lines with 4 measures and others with 3 measures. When I try to do this, I end up with both lines having the same width. I would like to the 3 measure lines to be shorter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly is! Just click after the end of the stave you want to change the length of. You can then move the last bar line of that stave, and so also move the whole stave.

If you look at the picture below, you'll see a little purple square after the end of the second stave. This appears if you left-click after the end of that stave:

[image]

Then, you select this purple square and drag it leftwards, until it is in the position you want the barline:

[image]

Also, just in case you don't know how to do it, to change the number of bars in a line of music, select the barline you want to be the last barline of that line and press return.

Comment: I tried that. If I click at the last bar line and try to drag it, it will stay in the same place and the notes will move instead. But, I am able to drag the beginning of the line, though.

Comment: I've added more info, you need to click *after* the barline.

Comment: And it should be a *left* click (not right, sorry!)

Comment: Ok. If I right click at the end, I get a menu.

Comment: Yes, I just updated that, too.

Comment: I don't see the purple thing when I left click.

Comment: Are you clicking in the position it appears in the first picture above?

Comment: yes. I did that. Does it matter if I got the sore scanned with PhotoScore?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use photoscore, so don't know.

Comment: I was able to get the purple thing by ticking layout marks in view. But they are not moving. Thank you for your answer -- now I know about purple things.

Comment: Once you have the purple square appear, make sure you drag the purple square, *not* the barline.

Comment: I finally managed to drag the small box. I had to tick Handles in view to get the box. To drag it, you have to move the cursor a lot -- it is not very responsive. Thanks.